# Javascript Function Won't Accept Variables As Parameters

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, arguments

So, I'm building on some old code, and I found that passing in variables as arguments in a function won't result in the expected outcome.

Ex:

```
someFunction("somestring");
```

will work fine. However,

```
var somestring = "somestring";
someFunction(somestring);
```

will not.
 What might be causing this? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

RESOLVED: I discovered the issue; it turns out there was an additional invisible character at the end of one of the strings, which was being read from a text file.

Comment: Correct; function is just an alias for a real function name.

Comment: @JoshuaJennings why not just post the actual code?

Comment: This is not real, can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), which reproduces the issue? What's the exact error message? The only thing I can imagine to cause this, is a non-printing character(s) within the code which doesn't work.

Comment: Or have you messed with the quotes in `somestring` declaration? Like Jeff said, please post your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var somestring = "somestring";
example(somestring);
example("somestring")


function example(string){
alert(string);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mk8rM/)